# Date and time as label didn't get on x-axis(Line chart) in mpandroidchart library?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to display date and time on x-axis but its not get.also it returns x-axis as blank.

My Code:-

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new Entry(1479249799770L, 98.3f));
        entries.add(new Entry(1479249799771L, 58.3f));
        entries.add(new Entry(1479249799772L, 78.3f));
        entries.add(new Entry(1479249799773L, 48.3f));
        entries.add(new Entry(1479249799774L, 68.3f));

        LineDataSet set1;

        // create a dataset and give it a type
        set1 = new LineDataSet(entries, "DataSet 1");
        set1.setFillAlpha(110);

        set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
        set1.setLineWidth(1f);
        set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        set1.setValueTextSize(9f);
        set1.setDrawFilled(false);

        mChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter());
        mChart.setViewPortOffsets(60, 0, 50, 60);

        //ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        //dataSets.add(set1);

        //LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        //LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, null);
        LineData data = new LineData();
        data.addDataSet(set1);
        mChart.setData(data);
```

also add MyAxisValueFormatter class for formatting x-axis values:-

```
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        // Simple version. You should use a DateFormatter to specify how you want to textually represent your date.

        Log.d("",""+value);
        Date date = new Date((long) value);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateString = formatter.format(date);
        return dateString;
    }
    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks.Suggest me What i did anything wrong in above code?

Comment: please print the log in  Log.d("dateString=",""+dateString);after getting dateString value

Comment: @dipali:-Thanks it only prints datestring value in log not on graph.

Comment: This log is not for printing in graph,.please tell me what will be show in log of datestring.

Comment: @dipali:-It only shows date..Its fine.but i need to display on x-axis of line chart.

Comment: i am saying that put log and check that the value of datstring will be print in log or not? if not then we will check another solution.is too radiculas.

Comment: public String getDateCurrentTimeZone(long timestamp) {
        try {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(timestamp));
            Log.d("timezone", "" + dateString);
            return dateString;


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return "";
    } I got the String and logs are here..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167599/discussion-between-dipali-and-sagar-potdar).

Answer (score 0):

These are my new entries x values i.e timestamp entries are wrong.
I tried below and get perfect graph.

```
 entries.add(new Entry(1451660400L, 98.3f));
    entries.add(new Entry(1451685600L, 58.3f));
    entries.add(new Entry(1451721600L, 78.3f));
    entries.add(new Entry(1451743200L, 48.3f));
    entries.add(new Entry(1451761200L, 68.3f));
```

and also get x-values label as date.